# How can I detect elapsed time in Pascal?

Tags: time, console, pascal, infinite-loop

I'm trying to create a simple game in Pascal. It uses the console. The goal in the game is to collect as many 'apples' as you can in 60 seconds. The game structure is a simple infinite loop. Each iteration, you can make one move. And here's the problem — before you make the move (`readKey`), time can pass as much as it wants. For example, the user can press a key after 10 seconds! Is there any way to count time? I need the program to know **when** user plays (before and after a key is pressed), so I don't know how to prevent user from "cheating".

Here's simple structure of my game:

```
begin
    repeat
        {* ... *}
        case ReadKey of
            {* ... *}
        end;
        {* ... *}
    until false;
end.
```

Full code: http://non.dagrevis.lv/junk/pascal/Parad0x/Parad0x.pas.

As far I know that there are two possible solutions:

1. getTime (from DOS),
2. delay (from CRT).

...but I don't know how to use them with my loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [this link](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/pas-wait.htm). There might be some useful information for you. And [here is](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/archive/index.php/t-3025.html) the same you're asking for. And [here's](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/f110.shtml) what you're looking for (same as the code below).

```
var hours: word;
    minutes: word;
    seconds: word;
    milliseconds: word;

procedure StartClock;
begin
  GetTime(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
end;

procedure StopClock;
var seconds_count : longint;
    c_hours: word;
    c_minutes: word;
    c_seconds: word;
    c_milliseconds: word;

begin
  GetTime(c_hours, c_minutes, c_seconds, c_milliseconds);
  seconds_count := c_seconds - seconds + (c_minutes - minutes) * 60 + (c_hours - hours) * 3600;
  writeln(inttostr(seconds_count) + ' seconds');
end;

begin
  StartClock;

  // code you want to measure

  StopClock;
end.
```